# Why is PbI₄ not composed of lead(II), iodide and triiodide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stability

$\ce{Pb^4+}$ is reduced by $\ce{I-},$ so $\ce{PbI4}$ cannot exist with $\ce{Pb}$ in $+4$ oxidation state. But if I replace three $\ce{I-}$ with $\ce{I3-},$ then we can have $\ce{Pb^2+}$ similar to $\ce{TlI3}$ which exists with $\ce{Tl+}.$ Why does this not happen?

Comment: $\ce{Pb^2+}$ prefers $\ce{[PbI4]^2-}$.

Comment: @Poutnik Then do we have any compounds where the triiodide and iodide ion exist simultaneously (a mixed salt)?

Comment: No idea, I cannot confirm nor reject it.

Comment: Partly because I have never even heard of a triiodide salt with a 2+ cation. Such compounds would likely decompose to give the normal iodide salt plus iodine. Even with a heavy alkali metal such as caesium, the triiodide ion is in effect partly decomposed, with one bond becoming longer than the other as if you had a complex of $\ce{I2}$ with a normal (mono)iodide ion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why triiodide ion does not form ionic bond with cation having +2 charge?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49589/why-triiodide-ion-does-not-form-ionic-bond-with-cation-having-2-charge)

Comment: @Poutnik and sometimes $\ce{[PbI3]-}$

Comment: @nilayghosh Sure, depending on $\ce{[I-]}$ :-) One cannot get one without another.